# Testing Python functions that require user input()

Tags: python, testing, pytest

I want to test the following function:

```
def get_inputs():
    str_from_user = input()
    list_of_marks = []
    while str_from_user != "exit":
        list_of_marks.append('!')
        str_from_user = input()
    return list_of_marks
```

is there a way to test multiple scenarios?
something like this (but only that works):

```
def test_get_inputs():
    assert get_inputs(){"hey", "coco", "milo", "exit"} == "!!!"
    assert get_inputs(){"exit"} == ""
    assert get_inputs(){"horses have long faces", "exit} == "!"
```

Comment: The actual goal should be to avoid writing functions with such side-effects. Write pure functions, that can be tested trivially.

Comment: mock `input` function.

Comment: You can use `mock`ing but I have only worked with `unittest` so not sure how it works with `pytest`. Though you should rethink the design of the tests.

Comment: One idea: give `get_inputs` a file-like object parameter `f` that defaults to `sys.stdin`, then use `f.readline()` instead of `input` to read the input. Then you can test your function with  a `io.StringIO` argument instead of mocking anything. Your production code can continue to call the function with no explicit argument to read from standard input.

Answer (score 2):

There is no obvious way to test your function as it is currently written, because you are reading from standard input. This is a side effect that makes your function non-[pure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function) and hard to test. In other words, the input comes from outside your program, so you do not have control over it.

You should rewrite your function in a way that makes it easy to provide input and check output *within* the program. You can do this passing a function to use as a way to get input instead of always using `input()`. Then, for testing, you can create a simple iterator object over a list of known inputs and pass its `__next__` method as input function.

Here's an example of how this could be done:

```py
def get_inputs(input_function):
    str_from_user = input_function()
    list_of_marks = []
    while str_from_user != "exit":
        list_of_marks.append('!')
        str_from_user = input_function()
    return list_of_marks

def test_get_inputs():
    input_func_one   = iter(["hey", "coco", "milo", "exit"]).__next__
    input_func_two   = iter(["exit"]).__next__
    input_func_three = iter(["horses have long faces", "exit"]).__next__
    assert get_inputs(input_func_one) == ['!', '!', '!']
    assert get_inputs(input_func_two) == []
    assert get_inputs(input_func_three) == ['!']
```

Another option, as suggested by [@chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner) in the above comments, would be to pass the function a file-like object, which can be easily mocked using the `io` module with either `BytesIO` or `StringIO`. Take care in this case though because `input()` strips the trailing newline, but `StringIO.readline()` does not.

```py
from io import StringIO

def get_inputs(input_file):
    str_from_user = input_file.readline().rstrip()
    list_of_marks = []
    while str_from_user != "exit":
        list_of_marks.append('!')
        str_from_user = input_file.readline().rstrip()
    return list_of_marks

def test_get_inputs():
    assert get_inputs(StringIO("hey\ncoco\nmilo\nexit\n")) == ['!', '!', '!']
    assert get_inputs(StringIO("exit\n")) == []
    assert get_inputs(StringIO("horses have long faces\nexit\n")) == ['!']
```

You could also adapt the first case (passing an input function) to work with `StringIO` by simply passing `StringIO("...").readline` as function.

---

Now that you have a function that is easily testable, you can write a simple wrapper that uses the function and works with standard input instead:

```py
# If using an input function
def get_inputs_from_stdin():
    return get_inputs(input)

# If using a file-like object
import sys

def get_inputs_from_stdin():
    return get_inputs(sys.stdin)
```